# AHK - How to ignore last 2 pressed keys from a set of 10 keys

Tags: autohotkey

I would be very grateful if I could find out how to create a script (ahk) that ignores the last 2 keys that were pressed.

Say for instance we have got A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I and J as our set of 10 keys.

I want the script to act in the following way:
upon script start:

```
-say key A is pressed - send custom action
-say key B is pressed - send custom action

-say Key A is pressed - send A
-say key B is pressed - send B

-say key C is pressed - send custom action
-say Key C is pressed - send C
-say Key B is pressed - send B
-say key A is pressed - send custom action again as the script would need to now ignore keys C and B (this is the part that im struggling with)
```

I have tried using A_PriorHotkey in a loop using error levels and GetKeyState but with no luck...

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This was quite a difficult question to understand,
but then again it was quite a difficult question to ask.
I believe I have the correct solution, or more or less correct,
it was quite an interesting challenge to code.
Wow, why do you need a script like this? Please explain a little bit.
I am now curious to know.

```
$a::
$b::
$c::
$d::
$e::
$f::
$g::
$h::
$i::
$j::
vLetter := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 1-1)
vLast2 := SubStr(vLog, 1-2)
if InStr(vLast2, vLetter)
SendInput %vLetter%
else
MyFunc(vLetter), vLog .= vLetter
Return

MyFunc(vLetter)
{
StringUpper, vLetter, vLetter
SendInput %vLetter%
Return
}
```